# Python Multiprocessing implementation problem - Pool.imap() seems to skip items from generator (glob.iglob())

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to parse certain .txt files containing data. And i'm trying to use multiprocessing to speed up the process. To first find those .txt files in a large directory i use `glob.iglob('/**/*.txt', recursive=True)` this is a generator that yields filepaths as they are found. So to use the generator in combination with multiprocessing, i implement `pool.imap()` to parse files as they are found. The following code is in my `if __name__ == '__main__'` section:

```
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
pool.imap(process_file, (filepath for filepath in glob.iglob(searchdirectory + '/**/*.txt', recursive=True)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This code seems to work fine at first, but when I look at the results it has skipped some files it should have found in the directory. Am I implementing something wrong? Or is it possibly a bug?

Comment: Did you wait until the whole process has finished? I am not sure how the filepaths are arranged.

Comment: @t_e_o If i'm correct the yielded filepaths should be assigned from the generator to workers when they are available. I'm not sure what happens when all workers are not available and the generator yields a file.

Comment: You need to consume the iterator from the imap so that close isn't called until all the results are produced.

Comment: @DanD. Is that not default behavior of `pool.close()`? If I read the docs correctly that should be the case. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close)